# Why I cannot set ANY value in IF condition?

Tags: c#, if-statement, default-value

I have 2 static variables like below

```
private static DateTime _currentPollStartDate = DateTime.MinValue; //As Default
private static DateTime _currentPollEndDate = DateTime.MinValue; //As Default
```

In a method, I try to set the values:

```
public void ProcessItems()
{
    var Items = GetItems();

    //In here, it reaches inside
    if (Items.HasItems)
    {
        //Items[0].PollStartDate.HasValue is TRUE
        //I can NOT set either Items[0].PollStartDate.Value or DateTime.MaxValue
        _currentPollStartDate = Items[0].PollStartDate.HasValue ? Items[0].PollStartDate.Value : DateTime.MaxValue;

        //Items[0].PollEndDate.HasValue is TRUE
        //I can NOT set either Items[0].PollEndDate.Value or DateTime.MaxValue
        _currentPollEndDate = Items[0].PollEndDate.HasValue ? Items[0].PollEndDate.Value : DateTime.MaxValue;
    }

    //...
}
```

But when I do this with `IF` I don't have the problem as stated above, why?

```
public void ProcessItems()
{
    var Items = GetItems();

    //In here, it reaches inside
    if (Items.HasItems)
    {
        if (Items[0].PollStartDate.HasValue)
            _currentPollStartDate = Items[0].PollStartDate.Value;
        if (Items[0].PollEndDate.HasValue)
            _currentPollEndDate = Items[0].PollEndDate.Value;
    }

    //...
}
```

Also, when I declare the variables `not static` this also solves my problem **even though** I use it like in my **first** code. But why can't I use both `static` and `if statement` as in my first code?

Edit:
Expected Value: something like 
_currentPollStartDate -> 2013-04-18 10:03:03

Result Value:
 _currentPollStartDate -> 0001-01-01 00:00:00  (This is not even MAX value)

Comment: What's does `PollStartDate` do?

Comment: What is the error? Run-time or compile-time? You say there's an error, but you don't actually say *what* the error is.

Comment: I suggest that you rephrase your question and clearly state what are the outputs in both cases and what is the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank to Ken Kin. With his latest comment, I thought to use of properties instead of simple declaration. So instead of this below:

```
private static DateTime _currentPollStartDate = DateTime.MinValue; //As Default
private static DateTime _currentPollEndDate = DateTime.MinValue; //As Default
```

I did as

```
private static DateTime CurrentPollStartDate { set; get; }
private static DateTime CurrentPollEndDate { set; get; }
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

static means "only once per class". so all instances of your class will use the same (by the exact meaning of the word) variable you defined as static. To make your code work use:

```
YourClassName._currentPollStartDate = Items[0].PollStartDate.HasValue ? Items[0].PollStartDate.Value : DateTime.MaxValue;
```

I don't know if you really want to have the same start and end date for all your polls which means the newest poll changes the start and end date of all your older polls.

Comment: the logic and what I do with the poll dates are not relevant at this point. And I use it with the SAME class, so I should not need to write as MyClassName._currentPollStartDate.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the type of `Items[0].PollStartDate.Value` and `DateTime.MaxValue`, when they are used with the trinary operator, both branches must be the same type.

`bool` and `bool?`, or `int` and `int?` are not the same type.

---

update:

I declared the following with no problem:

```
class MyClassName {
    private static DateTime _currentPollStartDate=DateTime.MinValue; //As Default
    private static DateTime _currentPollEndDate=DateTime.MinValue; //As Default

    public void ProcessItems() {
        var Items=GetItems();

        //In here, it reaches inside
        if(Items.HasItems) {
            //Items[0].PollStartDate.HasValue is TRUE
            //I can NOT set either Items[0].PollStartDate.Value or DateTime.MaxValue
            _currentPollStartDate=Items[0].PollStartDate.HasValue?Items[0].PollStartDate.Value:DateTime.MaxValue;

            //Items[0].PollEndDate.HasValue is TRUE
            //I can NOT set either Items[0].PollEndDate.Value or DateTime.MaxValue
            _currentPollEndDate=Items[0].PollEndDate.HasValue?Items[0].PollEndDate.Value:DateTime.MaxValue;
        }

        //...
    }

    public void _ProcessItems() {
        var Items=GetItems();

        //In here, it reaches inside
        if(Items.HasItems) {
            if(Items[0].PollStartDate.HasValue)
                _currentPollStartDate=Items[0].PollStartDate.Value;
            if(Items[0].PollEndDate.HasValue)
                _currentPollEndDate=Items[0].PollEndDate.Value;
        }

        //...
    }

    Items GetItems() {
        return new Items();
    }
}

class Items: List<Item> {
    public bool HasItems {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Item {
    public DateTime? PollStartDate {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime? PollEndDate {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its very interesting because I event asked help someone sitting next to me and we both looked at the situation and I was not able to set it WITHOUT making currentPollStartDate as Property

Comment: @ErayAcar: As I mentioned, you would need to provide the class definition that we can check for why.